# asp.net c# gridview sorting by an AJAX rating control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have added an Ajax rating control to my Gridview as below:

```
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Wrms_QueryId" HeaderText="Warms_QueryId" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Wrms_QueryId" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Favourites">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  CurrentRating='<%# Bind("num") %>' MaxRating="3" RatingAlign="Horizontal"
                        RatingDirection="LeftToRightTopToBottom" StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar"
                        FilledStarCssClass="filledRatingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="emptyRatingStar" Tag='<%# Bind("Wrms_QueryId")%>' OnChanged="Rating1_Changed">
                    </asp:Rating>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

and in .cs

```
 protected void Rating1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rating ra= (Rating)sender; 
    GridViewRow gr=(GridViewRow) ra.Parent.Parent;          

    // table update required?

    Rating r = sender as Rating;
     int id = Convert.ToInt32(r.Tag);
     int lf = Convert.ToInt32(r.CurrentRating);
     string strSQL2 = "UPDATE [dbo].[wrms_config_m] set QueryId = " + lf + " where  Wrms_QueryId = " + id;
     ExecuteSQLUpdate(strSQL2);


}
```

but I don't know how to add sorting to the rating column. Normally I would just add SortExpression="####" but this doesn't seem to be supported for the rating column.

I have looked through lots of forums and can't find an answer. any help would be gratefully received please.

thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with this control, but if you want the grid to re-sort itself on the change, wouldn't you have to rebind the grid?  And if the "current rating" is bound to "num", shouldn't "num" be the SortExpression for the BoundColumn?

Comment: thanks Ann L. You may be right regarding the rebind but as this is an Ajax control doesn't appear to be needed. The sort Expression and allow sorting properties just don't appear to be supported or make any difference to this control.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, resolved this myself. I was adding the sort to the wrong line. needed to be on

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Favourites" SortExpression="num">
```